# Turn a list of lists of lists of lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.6 and I need to turn the list below into a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
myList = [['A',[['a',1],['b',0],['c',1]]],['B',[['a',0],['b',1],['c',1]]]]
```

Output:

```
myDict = {A: {a: 1, b: 0, c: 1}, B: {a: 0, b: 1, c: 1}}
```

I tried to use:

```
myDict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for key1, key2, *values in myList:
    myDict[key1][key2].extend(values)
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprehensions got your back:

```
{ k:{ kk:vv for kk, vv in v } for k, v in myList }
# => {'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, 'B': {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}}
```

Comment: You can get even more concise: `{k: dict(v) for k, v in myList}`